# Override "rspec" command to run tests

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

This seems simple but I can't find a reputable solution via Google or searching SO.

I'm using foreman with a Rails 4 app to load ENV via a .env file. To run my tests properly, I have to execute `foreman run rspec [optional files]`.

This gets tedious and occasionally I forget the `foreman run` part.  I'd like to override the `rspec` command for a single app so that:

`rspec [files]`  => `foreman start [files]`

Looked at binstubs but I don't fully understand them and they don't look exactly like what I want.

I can create a bash script that does this, but now that's specific to my local machine instead of built into the app codebase.

Comment: If you don't want a bash solution, which would be trivial, why do you apply the bash tag? It's simply a time-waster for people prepared to answer bash questions who don't know much about ruby (like me).

Comment: write a bash script and put it under `script/spec` or whatever you think would be an appropriate name. this is a good convention to follow. otherwise, just create an alias in your bashrc file, so that you can alias `rspec` to `foreman run rspec`

Comment: @rici, I actually ended up going with a bash script since it was the cleanest solution.  I would have preferred a non-bash solution but that would have been much more trouble than it was worth. I've added the script I used below. If you have any good recommendations to the script I'd welcome them as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a script in my ~/scripts folder (where I store my own scripts added to my PATH).

Here's what I have in ~/scripts/tester (with executable permissions):

```
#!/bin/bash

#==================================================
# Created: 2014-04-01 / Updated: 2014-04-01
# Desc: Shorten syntax to run tests properly.
#==================================================

# For developers who may not use bash at all...
# $0 = filename and path
# $1 = first arg...

cmd="foreman run rspec $1"

echo "#--------------------------------------------------"
echo "# EXECUTING: $0"
echo "# '$cmd'"
echo "#--------------------------------------------------"

$cmd
```

I can execute with `tester` in my rails app directory and it will run `foreman run rspec` which executes all tests or I can pass in specific files or wildcard-names and it will run the matched tests.

It outputs the file location so if I pass this script on to others they know what files being run so they can modify it...I do this because I've actually run into a situation where a new developer was Googling a "tester" script for rails wondering why he couldn't find it as part of core rails...this way newbies know exactly what's being run and where the file's located at.

Chose `tester` as the script name because it wouldn't clash with any other known commands AFAIK.

Sample input:

`tester` => `foreman run rspec # all specs`

`tester spec/models` => `foreman run rspec spec/models # run all model specs`